# appending html into the dom, then when i use an on(click) function I get $this is undefined

Tags: jquery, dom, undefined, this, document-ready

I have a list of stuff, i want to insert some extra options after the dom is loaded.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

//add sharing to stages
    var $stage = $('.stage > h3'),
    $stageShareBtn = $('.stage h3');

    $stage.append('<i class="fa fa-share"></i>');
    $stage.after('<div class="share-stage"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>').end;

    $stage.on( 'click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $this.next('.share-stage').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

The append and after worked fine, jquery is hooked up correctly. If I leave the $this off the function, it works but triggers all on the page.

Comment: `$(this)`. `$this` is just a variable that's undefined. `this` would be correct - that's core javascript. `$()` is the jquery wrapper function.

Comment: Souldn't this be $(this)?

Comment: ha, i totally spaced on that. yup, that did it. cheers!